# Wirecloud / FI-ware Widget: Exception catched input endpoint

Tags: javascript, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm working on a widget for the mashup platform at fi-ware.
Until now it worked very well, but after I made a few tweaks at the code it says when it gets executed that

```
Exception catched while processing an event that reached the "input" input endpoint
```

But I use the registerCallback method with input as paramter, so I don't know where the problem is.

Is there another reason to get one of these exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is displayed when a widget or operator raises an exception while processing an event (in your case, an event that came from the "input" input endpoint).

You should be able to obtain more details about the exception clicking on the "Details" section that appears near the log entry:

[image]

In this case, the exception was raised at line `15` of the `js/main.js` file. Take into account that currently WireCloud doesn't remove the part of the stack trace related to the internal code of WireCloud (the stack trace part of WireCloud starts at the line of Endpoint.propagate), we are working on removing it to make more clear those stack traces.

You can also debug those problems by using the developers tools provided by your browser. You only need to ensure your developer tools are configured to stop on any exception (including caught ones). E.g. on Chromium/Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Yes I got such exceptions to, but in this case it just sayed the above. Nothing more. And the Debugger wasnt very helpful for that.

Comment: are you using a custom instance of WireCloud? Can you reproduce it again? If yes, please, create a ticket using the [WireCloud's issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues) and attach the info for reproducing it.

Comment: No its the normal one. I will try to, if I will get it again i will make a ticket

Comment: I could reproduce it, I opened a ticket

Comment: ticket closed and applied to the Mashup portal :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by fixing an error in the javascript code.
So it seems to be a normal error there, but it doesn't tell you where(Very useful)

If someone got a more precise answer for that please answer it!